# Code on browser console using c#

Tags: c#, object, browser, console, return

Good day,

Is it possible to code on **c# connecting to browser console** and do this line for example
[image]

and when it returns an object for example
[image]

then I could get the return object on c#.
Thank you.

Additional information to the concern:
I use **html and javascript only**

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/sidorares/crconsole

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to the browser console, you need to do it at the client using javascript. You might use C# code at the server to *write* a page that *includes* some client-side javascript calls, but: the server does not have *direct* access to a client's console.

Note: some frameworks might expose features to *automate* this, but they will just be doing the same thing as above.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `XMLHttpRequest` to submit the javascript object to server, and if you are using asp.net than you will get your submitted values in HttpContext request object

Comment: Thank you for your response, I only use HTML and javascript nothing else.